# Date problem in Google Chrome/Android

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, date, browser

For some reason I need to test current and previous dates with Javascript Date Object. 
I changed my system time with back date i.e. 25th July 2011 and time 9:00PM.
I used following code:

```
<html>
         <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload = function(){

                var d = new Date();
                alert("Date = "+ d.toString());
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
</html>
```

If I run the above code in Firefox then the output is: 
     Date = Mon Jul 25 2011 21:03:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

But if I run the same code in Chrome/Android then the output is: 
     Date = Tue Jul 26 2011 21:03:06 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)

**Note: I am using Chrome 12.0.742.122**
**Please change your machine's Date.**
**I am using windows 7**

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with Google Chrome with Date? or If can suggest me what should I do to overcome Chrome's behaviour?

Please suggest if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: I'm getting the same date on Firefox and Chrome. I'm not sure what causes your problem.

Comment: this a is bug in Chrome. their is nothing goes wrong in specification for this thing

Answer (score 1):

There is an [open bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17155) in Chromium regarding this issue.

Seems like it is happening only when you change the time backwards, so maybe you run your test by changing it forward.

Comment: Thanks Amit, yes you are right, if I change date to some forward date then it works on Google Chrome but on Android, it just take current date only whether I change date with backward or forward.